# println cannot be resolved as a variable

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, java-stream

I am studying object oriented programming in my university and my professors is making an example of streams on java. Unfortunately when I try to run this code it says "println cannot be resolved as a variable" on `System.out::println`. 
It also says to delete the two colons,
while on my professor's eclipse it does work.

This is the code. I am running it on eclipse for ubuntu and my version of java is 1.8 update 91

```
package stream;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class StreamExamples {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String text = "I have no idea what is the problem";
        String[] words = text.split(" ");

        Arrays.stream(words)        
        .sorted()
        .limit(3)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which Version of eclipse r u using?

Comment: Code seems fine and to verify I executed it on my local machine (1.8) with as result the following output: `I
have
idea` each on a separate line. Are you sure that you execute the main class with JVM 1.8 (try on command line).

Comment: @Jägermeister Version: 3.8.1

Comment: Hint: maybe you should tell your professor that he should not only instruct you to use latest greatest JDKs, but that the eclipse version also matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely the version of Eclipse you are running does not understand Java 8 syntax.

You need to be running the current Eclipse 4.6 (Neon) or the previous release 4.5 (Mars) for full Java 8 support. You code works fine on Eclipse Neon.

Comment: Eclipse Luna does too.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check your build path by right clicking on your project, *Build Path > Configure Build Path*. The libraries tab should show a JRE with version 1.8, if that is not the case, click *Edit* and select a JRE that is at least version 8.

2) Check the compiler settings by right clicking on your project, *Properties > Java Compiler*. Change the *Compiler compliance level* to 1.8.

Comment: Hint: your answer is simply going in the wrong direction. Thing is: eclipse has its own java compiler; and if that internal compiler isn't matching up ... then it really doesn't help to point to a more recent JDK. Therefore your answer is missing the point.

Comment: You mean like changing the (internal) compiler level to 1.8? ;-)

Comment: How would you do that when your version of eclipse is pre 1.8 ? That is my point: a newbie might not understand that "the menus don't show 1.8" translates to "you need a newer version of eclipse".

Comment: That's true - I assumed that a recent version of eclipse was in play since he mentioned that he was just starting out (e.g. just downloaded current version from eclipse.org).
Sometimes I run into a similar problem while importing a maven project that did not specify its wanted compiler settings. In that case the superpom kicks in and sets everything to version 1.5. Updating the build path usually solves that problem.